# How to make a Jquery function to write a Div instead of a Textbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I  have a **jquery function** which gets data from a json php mysql. And the results are appearing in **textboxes**

```
function renderDetails(wine) {
$('#Id').val(wine.id);
    $('#question').val(wine.question);
    $('#answer').val(wine.answer);
    $('#link').val(wine.link).html();
}
```

**The textboxes in HTML are like this**

```
<label>link:</label>
<input type="text" id="link" name="link"/>
```

Instead of a text box I would like to bring the  link to a div!

```
<p id="link">This is where the link should appear.</p>
```

**How would you write the jquery in order to feed the DIV** ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, that's not a `div`.  That's a `p`.  But beyond that, you can simply use [the `.text()` function](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to set the contents of any such element:

```
$('#link').text(wine.link);
```

Or, [for HTML content](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$('#link').html(wine.link);
```

Comment: Thank you very much not only for your answer but for your explanation!

Comment: Could you tell me also how can I brink the link in a click-able format inside the <p> tag ?

Comment: @kost: It should be clickable if it's HTML and is appended with the `.html()` function.  Can you demonstrate some code where that's not the case?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#link").html( wine.link );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#link').html(wine.link);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$("#link")..text()

$("#link")..html()

or

$("#link").append()
```

depending in what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

My dear friend you are putting the fetched data into the element which id is  link.
look into your code you will find that your input element also have the same id "***link***".
Otherwise you are doing good. Remember your html page can't have more than one element per id.
cheers.